# What is the best way to secure/link an Air Application to a specified system

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, uuid, flex4.5

I have to build (obviously using flex) an AIR application that must be linked to a given hardware (i.e. hard-disk), so it can't be copied elsewhere..

Usually using others languages, every time you open the application, a comparison between HardDisk or CPU ID and the value stored in the application itself...

Using Flex this is not possible (as far as I know)...

User/Password check obviously won't work..
I can't use a webservice, the application needs to work offline too..

How could I do?

Comment: is my question really so bad? why a downote? :S

Comment: dont understand why you have a downvote.... people dont leave any reason. it so stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AIR you can integrate native apps - either indirectly (start a process and get its result) or directly (as a library).

Any of these techniques allow you to achieve your goal the same way you would in the case you described as "other languages"... BUT BEWARE: this makes your app platform-dependent AND can potentially lead to problems since it is prone to permissions issues etc.

Another point: no such technique is 100% secure (can be circumvented AND can lead to unsatisfied legitimate users!) - so you should really consider whether this is the way to go...